# Excel - update a cell value when another cell changes without VBA

Tags: timestamp, excel-formula

I want to set a timestamp in a cell when the user changes another cell, but without VBA, as I want this to work in macro-less situations. All solutions I've found use Worksheet_Change VBA code, so I need an answer without VBA.

Example: The user updates column A. I want column B to record the timestamp when the user changes column A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution to the problem. It requires a trick, in that you have to turn on iterative calculations, because this approach takes advantage of circular references. So, this will only work in a workbook that otherwise doesn't need iterative calculations.

1. Turn on iterative calculations, but set the max iterations to 1.
2. In column B of each row, where the timestamp will go, use this formula. So for row 2, cell B2 will contain:
   `=IF(AND(A2<>"",C2<>A2),NOW(),IF(A2="","n/a",B2))`
3. In column C (or any other unused column), put this formula. So for row 2, cell C2 will contain:
   `=IF(A2="","",IF(OR(B2="",AND(ISNUMBER(C2),A2=C2)),C2,A2))`

That's it. The result will look like this. You can format the timestamp to other values of course:

`|        A             B             C     |
1|   User Entry     Timestamp       Prev    |
2|      dog         6:28:55 PM      dog     |
3|      cat         7:17:42 PM      cat     |
4|                     n/a                  |`

The C column stores the value of A so that when A is changed, the formulas know that A has changed values. The timestamp won't change if the user enters the 'dog' cell but leaves 'dog' as the value. And the timestamp of row 2 doesn't change when you change cell A in some other row, which is a problem of some excel solutions that capture timestamps.

Comment: This worked for me.  Though I had to figure out how to turn on iterative calculations.  I found it on [Microsoft's web site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-in-excel-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4).  Look for the Q&A section for "Change the number of times Excel iterates a formula".

Comment: @JMan Good point. I should add that the way you turn on iterative calculations varies with the age of the Excel version you’re using, so until all the old versions are gone, there may be other places people need to look for the way to turn it on.